# upgrading Ubuntu 11.10 to 16.04LTS - can I skip in between upgrades?

Tags: upgrade

I'm upgrading an old laptop running Ubuntu 11.10. Do I need to upgrade sequentially through all the versions until i get to the current to 16.04. Is there a quicker way - can I skip in between upgrades?

Comment: You can upgrade from one LTS to another or from each version to the next one, so you need to upgrade to 12.04 (normal version upgrade) , then to 14.04 (LTS upgrade) and then you can upgrade to 16.04 (LTS upgrade). But upgrading to all that versions, wouldn't it be much easier and way faster to make a fresh and clean installation of 16.04?!

Comment: Theoretically, you can do what you want.  It's just not recommended.

Comment: Sorry but your system does not seem to hold any valuable data so wipe the disk and install 16.04. And yes... this comment is intended to be harsh: using 11.10 is an insult to your personal data.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip versions when doing LTS-to-LTS upgrades, e.g. you can go from 11.10 to 12.04 LTS, then to 14.04 LTS, and then to 16.04 LTS.

However, this will take a long time, you are probably looking at 3-4 hours minimum there depending on your internet connection and other factors.

Since this is a substantial migration, you should also expect small things here and there to go a bit wrong, so this might mean even more effort to get things going smoothly after you are finished.

As you have hopefully backed up your data like you always should when doing upgrades, the quickest and cleanest way would be to do do a fresh install of 16.04 LTS, you can get away with 20-30 minutes here.

*Just as a side note, if you tend to wait this long with upgrading your installations, I'd suggest to stick with LTS releases.*